# Why are staves class-dependent?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, designer-reasons

**Why can any player use a wand, but magical staves have class limitations?**

- Is there historical context for this?
- Is there any commentary on the topic from Crawford or others with
  "authority"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is for historical reasons based on the intent of E. Gary Gygax when he designed Advanced Dungeon & Dragons. There are a couple of staff items not found in classic D&D and it looks like the 5e author followed Gygax's lead.

In OD&D the Staff of Healing and the Snake Staff were both noted as a clerical. When Gygax created AD&D he expanded this to restrict the staves to certain classes.

Likely he did this for flavor reasons. For example, the Staff of Healing and the Snake Staff evoke some of the Bible stories and certainly De Mille's *Ten Commandments* with Heston had an impact on the popular image of staves that can heal and turn into snakes. The Staff of Power and the Staff of Wizardry evoke various traditional tropes held about wizards.

Comment: For future reference to the OP, if you see a rule in 5e that makes you think, "Why did they do that in particular?" I would advise you cross-reference with AD&D first; WOTC attempted very hard to bring back what people liked about AD&D in 5e.

Comment: Interesting idea, but can you back this up? Right now it’s just a bare assertion/speculative relation.

Comment: I think it should be noted that in OD&D and at least until 3rd edition, _not_ all classes could use wands (with perhaps a few exceptions, such as treasure or trap detection) so this assumption of OP's question could be addressed as well.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov open up the AD&D Player's Handbook and DMG then compare. Like most of the classes in 5e it is obvious what the source was as to why those classes are included.